# Android 11 not granting permission .Statuses folder

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, android-11

```
File[] listFiles = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WA Saver Test").listFiles();
```

it's work and give images files path

But when I use

```
File[] listFiles = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses").listFiles();
```

It's not work in android 11 and don't give files path

Answer (score 1):

simply you can't access other apps private data folders now, thats the purpose of introducing [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). at least there is an API for media files, check out your options in table posted [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

you can also use [`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access) new permission, but you will be probably [rejected from Google Play Store](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play)